# Passing a lambda function as a variable to another function in timeit

Tags: python, lambda, arguments, timeit

I have a Python function called `func` that I am trying to time using `timeit`.

`func` takes an argument, `f`, that is also a function. In the program I'm writing, it's a lambda function, but it can be a regularly defined function as well. What matters is that the source code for this function is not available to `func`, all that's available is a reference to it.

What I'm trying to do:

```
def testTimingOfFunc(f):
    time = timeit.timeit("package.func(f)", "from src import package")
```

I get an error that says that `f` isn't defined.

Everything else is working correctly. When I call:

```
testTimingOfFunc('lambda x:x**2')
```

and change the function to:

```
def testTimingOfFunc(f):
    time = timeit.timeit("package.func(" + str(f) + ")",
                         "from src import package")
```

everything works as it should, so I know that everything regarding the `timeit` function is fine.

That's not how `testTimingOfFunc` works though; A function reference gets passed in, not a string.

Any ideas on how I can pass `f` as an argument to `func` in `timeit`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

timeit can be called with a python callable value: just change your method to:

```
from src import package
import functools

def testTimingOfFunc(f):
    time = timeit.timeit(functools.partial(package.func, f))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store a reference to `f` in the namespace of `package`. Be careful that you don't have name conflicts though

```
def testTimingOfFunc(f):
    from src import package
    package.f = f
    time = timeit.timeit("package.func(package.f)", "from src import package")
```

Answer (score 0):

`timeit.Timer` accepts a no-argument function as one of its parameters:

```
def tester(f):
    from src import package
    def wrapper():
        package.func(f)
    return wrapper

def foo(x):
    return x * 2

print(timeit.timeit(tester(foo)))
```